# How to reduce OpenCL enqueue time/any other ideas?

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpu, gpgpu, hardware-acceleration

I have an algorithm and I've been trying to accelerate it using OpenCL on my nVidia.

It has to process a large amount of data (let's say 100k to milions), where for each one datum: a matrix (on the device) has to be updated first (using the datum and two vectors); and only after the whole matrix has been updated, the two vectors (also on the device) are updated using the same datum. So, my host code looks something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < milions; i++) {
        clSetKernelArg(kernel_matrixUpdate, 7, sizeof(int), (void *)&i); 
        clSetKernelArg(kernel_vectorsUpdate, 4, sizeof(int), (void *)&i);       
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel_matrixUpdate, 1, NULL, &global_item_size_Matrix, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel_vectorsUpdate, 1, NULL, &global_item_size_Vectors, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);}
```

Unfortunately, this loop takes longer to execute than the kernels themselves. So my questions are:

- Is there any way to enqueue N kernels more efficiently?
- Is there any way to update the whole matrix first and then update the vectors, without using separate kernels? E.g. does the device run the kernels in order, (i.e. first workgroup with 0,1,...,63; second workgroup with 64,...)? But I guess that would be a bad practice anyway...
- Any other ideas? :D

Every feedback or opinion will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Fastest is device side enqueue using OpenCL 2.0 dynamic parallelism. Also if kernel parameters are always same, no need to re-set them with clSetKernelArg. Once is enough. Kernels run in-order by default if you don't specifty out-of-order flag in creation of it. Also why `(void *)&i`? It is getting an address of variable so all kernelarguments will get the same latest value of it. They will all see `millions-1` value. If only that parameter is changed, you can add a second kernel to increment that value in gpu memory, then enqueue them in device by device. At least this would skip CPU side.

Comment: Then you would only enqueue a parent kernel only once. If each operation is independent of another, you can use multiple command queues (maybe up to 64 of them) to run multiple kernels concurrently.

Comment: Unfortunately, nVidia doesn't seem to support OpenCL 2.0 at the moment :(

Comment: Sounds like your problem is not with OpenCL, it's that your algorithm is sequential. Are you sure you can't change the algorithm so it can batch updates? At absolute minimum, if you're so API-bound, an obvious step would be to combine your 2 kernels into 1. (can you relate the matrix size to vector size?) But you won't get much help beyond that unless you actually post the nature of your algorithm, because that's what needs optimising.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload all your data to GPU and then call a kernel with one work item per element, instead of the for loop.

Generally, when going from CPU to GPU, the outermost "for" loop becomes a kernel invocation.