# Why are opencl enqueue commands so time consuming?

Tags: performance, gpu, opencl, gpgpu

I am trying to do live audio processing using the Intel HD Graphics GPU. I theory they should be perfect for this. But I am surprised at cost of the enqueuing commands. This looks to be a prohibiting factor, and by far the most time-consuming step.

In short calling the enqueueXXXXX commands take a long time. Actually doing the data copying and executing the kernel is sufficiently fast. Is this just an inherent problem with the OpenCL implementation, or am I doing something wrong?

Data copying + kernel execution takes about 10us
Calling the enqueue commands takes about 300us - 500us

The code is available at https://github.com/tblum/opencl_enqueue/blob/master/main.cpp

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        cl::Event copyToEvent;
        cl::Event copyFromEvent;
        cl::Event kernelEvent;
        auto t1 = Clock::now();
        commandQueue.enqueueWriteBuffer(clIn, CL_FALSE, 0, 10 * 48 * sizeof(float), frameBufferIn, nullptr, &copyToEvent);
        OCLdownMix.setArg(0,clIn);
        OCLdownMix.setArg(1,clOut);
        OCLdownMix.setArg(2,(unsigned int)480);
        commandQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(OCLdownMix, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(480), cl::NDRange(48), nullptr, &kernelEvent);
        commandQueue.enqueueReadBuffer(clOut, CL_FALSE, 0, 10 * 48 * sizeof(float), clResult, nullptr, &copyFromEvent);
        auto t2 = Clock::now();
        commandQueue.finish();
        auto t3 = Clock::now();
        cl_ulong copyToTime = copyToEvent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>() -
                              copyToEvent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>();
        cl_ulong kernelTime = kernelEvent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>() -
                              kernelEvent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>();
        cl_ulong copyFromTime = copyFromEvent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>() -
                              copyFromEvent.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>();
        std::cout << "Enqueue: " << t2 - t1 << ", Total: " << t3 - t1 << ", GPU: " << (copyToTime+kernelTime+copyFromTime) / 1000.0 << "us"<< std::endl;
     }
```

Output:

```
Enqueue: 1804us, Total: 4322us, GPU: 10.832us
Enqueue: 485us, Total: 668us, GPU: 10.666us
Enqueue: 237us, Total: 419us, GPU: 10.499us
Enqueue: 282us, Total: 474us, GPU: 10.832us
Enqueue: 345us, Total: 531us, GPU: 10.082us
Enqueue: 359us, Total: 555us, GPU: 10.915us
Enqueue: 345us, Total: 524us, GPU: 10.082us
Enqueue: 327us, Total: 504us, GPU: 10.416us
Enqueue: 363us, Total: 540us, GPU: 10.333us
Enqueue: 442us, Total: 595us, GPU: 10.916us
```

I found this related question: [How to reduce OpenCL enqueue time/any other ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786300/how-to-reduce-opencl-enqueue-time-any-other-ideas) 
But no useful answers for my situation.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks 
BR Troels

Comment: Strange observation: Everything runs a little faster if I use blocking data copy. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: I'd suspect the kernel executes quickly because has not much to do. In other words doesn't seem to be enough computationally intensive. Beside you don't seem to pass any data - I can see buffer allocated but no data copied into it - so it either operates on zeros or garbage. That probably won't matter but it's better to use some real data.

Comment: @doqtor The question is why enqueueing is slow. The rest is just kept simple to illustrate the problem.

Comment: "Data copying + kernel execution takes about 10us Calling the enqueue commands takes about 300us - 500us" - you base your opinion on the fact that enqueueing is slow because tasks on the GPU side take shorter time. Can you show us data from a reliable source proving that enqueueing times on your hardware should be shorter?

Comment: @doqtor No my opinion is that 300us to put some commands in a queue is very slow in absolute terms on a modern cpu. The CPU delivers aprox 50GFLOPS The GPU is physically on the same die as the GPU, and has access to the same physical memory. 
If the OpenCL framework is just that slow, then so be it. Then it is just unusable for my use case, and that would be surprising to me.

Comment: In my setup (Ubuntu,gcc) I got enqueue 80us, gpu: 8us (blocking version 40us/4us). Your code suggests you are using Windows and here my question is if your binary is build in Release mode. If you are using Visual Studio debug mode has much higher overhead than gcc and in cmake you don't specify to use Release and afair on VS it defaults to Debug. If not this then the timings of enqueue may be affected by the speed of your CPU, whatever else is happening in your OS, the priority of your process and so on. You could also try to link with different libOpenCL vendor to check the timings.

Comment: May be capturing `CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED`and `CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_SUBMIT` would give more information